# VBA FOR loop runs for two loops

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to copy and paste a list of names from one worksheet to a specific cells in another sheets, depends on the row # in the "List" sheet is even or odd.

However, the FOR loop only runs for two loops : ie. ONE loop for name in row # even and ONE loop for name in row # odd.

Can anyone tell me where is my mistake?

I took away the IF function, and everything works well. But i need the IF function to determine Odd/Even row number.

My current code as below:

```
Sub Update_Print()


Dim i As Integer

For i = 7 To 1000
    Sheets("List").Select
    If i Mod 2 > 0 Then

        Cells(i, 1).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Receipts").Select
        Cells(i + 30, 4).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

     Else
        Cells(i, 1).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Receipts").Select
        Cells(i + 30, 10).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

    ActiveSheet.Print

Exit For

End If


Next i



End Sub
```

Comment: It's because you have the `Exit For` inside the `Else`, so once you run the loop the second time, `i = 8`, so `i Mod 2 = 0`, so you enter the `Else` section, and at the end you reach your `Exit For` and you exit the `For` loop.

Comment: Ah yes, I see it now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

the for loop and if..else loop are probably misplaced.

May I suggest the following instead, which also tries to avoid the use of copy-pasting which usually slows the execution time.

```
Sub Update_Print()

Dim i As Integer
Dim sht1, sht2 As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Set sht1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("List")
Set sht2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Receipts")

sht1.Activate
For i = 7 To 1000

    If i Mod 2 > 0 Then
        sht1.Cells(i, 1) = sht2.Cells(i + 30, 4)
    Else
        sht1.Cells(i, 1) = sht2.Cells(i + 30, 10)
    End If

Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
sht1.PrintOut

End Sub
```

Are you trying to print the sheet after the macro runs? I've noticed the placement of your `ActiveSheet.Print` might be in a rather dangerous position, as it would be printing your activesheet about 1000 times! I've allocated it outside of the loop instead after the complete execution of the `For Loop`.

This method would be faster for copying values, but it doesn't bring across any formatting.

Comment: on the else section, the first sht2 might be a sht1 ? And if format is necessary, you can also avoid `select` with code like `sht1.cells(i,1).copy sht2.cells(i+30,4)` , for example

Comment: thanks for spotting that. it's been fixed @PatrickLepelletier

Comment: Yes, i see the problem with my End For loop now. I tried the "=" method. It erases the data in all the cells (i, 1) in sht1 though. Weird.

Comment: Ah yes lol. In the 'if then else' , all the sht1 and 2 are reversed :(

Comment: Yes! Thanks alot!